# How to get text area content using selenium web driver

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I have the following element(text area). The value of this text area won't appear in the html code. But that will be displayed in webpage when page is loaded. How to get the value using selenium and python.

`<textarea id="query" class="textarea" cols="37" rows="30"></textarea>`

Comment: Can you show us a working example, esp. the URL? What did you try so far?

Comment: did you try browser.find_element_by_id('query').text ?

Answer (score 8):

The contents of the `textarea` will be shown in it's `value` property, just like `input` elements. So something like (pseudo-Python)

```
 contents = driver.find_element_by_id('query').get_attribute('value')
```

Comment: What if there is no `value` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

one thing which you can do is capture a screenshot of that area using and extract the text later using tesseract. Got same issue as text entered is not being stored in value attribute
EG:

## to capture screenshot

```
featureElement = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea//..")
featureElement.screenshot('foo.png')
```

#to read from image

```
images = cv2.imread('image_path')
```

## convert to grayscale image

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(images, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

## memory usage with image i.e. adding image to memory

```
filename = "{}.jpg".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
print(text)
```