# get text from textarea tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have textarea as `<textarea placeholder="Enter text" style="resize: none;"></textarea>`

The textarea has some text. But it's not displayed between tags. How can I get it.

e.g. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea[placeholder=""Enter text"]').text`

Comment: wait you mean you want the value of 'placeholder'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get text area content using selenium web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005059/how-to-get-text-area-content-using-selenium-web-driver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get `value` attribute:

```
value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea[placeholder=""Enter text"]').get_attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be dealing angular code, so you'll want to get the value attribute instead:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea[placeholder=""Enter text"]')

text = element.get_attribute(“value”)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only know for sure if this will work for you if I see your page HTML, but the following xpath should find any `textarea` element with `placeholder` of "Enter text":

```
"//textarea[@placeholder = 'Enter text']"
```

so your line of code would be

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@placeholder = 'Enter text']").text
```